# React-native app: navigation.navigate is not a function

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-navigation

(In 'navigation.navigate("Home")', 'navigation.navigate' is undefined)

```js
const handleLogin = () => {
    auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((userCredentials) => {
        const user = userCredentials.user;
        console.log("Logged in with:", user.email);
        navigation.navigate("Home");
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  };
```

How can I fix this? I want to make it so that when I press the Login button, user is identified and then I go from login screen to home screen.

Comment: Where is your `navigation` object coming from?

Comment: const handleLogin = ({navigation}) => {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create **navigation** object by **useNavigation** hook like this.

```
const navigation = useNavigation()
```

For using **useNavigation** you need to install **@react-navigation/native**

```
npm i @react-navigation/native
```

Then import **useNavigation** from **@react-navigation/native**

```
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native'
```

Then you can navigate easily

```
const navigation = useNavigation()
navigation.navigate("Home")
```

Comment: Not necessarily, if the screen is defined in a navigator , then the useNavigation hook is not needed.

Comment: Thanks man that really helped solve one of my errors!